# ubuntu 12.10 lessc 1.3.3 installation

Tags: installation, 12.10, css

I cannot install lessc 1.3.3 installation.
sudo apt-get install node-less version 1.3.0
I googled but I cannot found a solution.

is that any alternative exist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If lessc 1.3.0 is too old for you, the alternative is to use npm, the package manager for node.js modules. This leads to the second issue: the node.js packaged in Ubuntu only provides a "nodejs" binary, not "node". The ["proper"](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu) way to fix this is to use [Chris Lea's PPA](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu) to avoid using Ubuntu node packages entirely. If at some point your node.js is too old for your needs, use those PPAs. But for now the quick&dirty solution is to create a symbolic link from /usr/bin/node to /usr/bin/nodejs to be able to use packages from npm:

1. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`
2. Uninstall the Ubuntu lessc: `sudo apt-get autoremove node-less`.
3. install the latest less! `sudo npm install -g less`

The result:

```
$ lessc --version
lessc 1.3.3 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

Comment: Node-less 1.3 does looks to be available in launchpad: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/112784871/node-less_1.3.0~20120310-1ubuntu1_all.deb Am I incorrect or are these different?

Comment: @maggotbrain This appears to be less.js, the client-side JavaScript version of less, not lessc, the lesscompiler.

Comment: Maybe it also contains lessc (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/armhf/node-less/1.3.0~20120310-4). I'll check and then maybe recommend using universe instead. Thanks!

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I wasn't familiar enough with the packages to give a confident answer. +1

Comment: @maggotbrain Actually, after reading carefully the question, he has lessc 1.3.0 from Universe (otherwise node-less doesn't exist anyway) and wants the 1.3.3 version. I made sure to talk about 1.3.3 instead of only 1.3.

Comment: thanks @JenniferWilson, now I have 1.3.3 version. I needed 1.3.3 version for twitter boostrap.less, now it's working.